# Python : Interruption between sending chunks via uart

Tags: python, serial-port, uart, interruption, bytestream

I'm sending some data via uart. I take single file and split it into 5120byte parts(chunks). Between sending this chunks there is interruption (probably based on baudrate value) I need to catch this interruption and switch from sending data to receiving data. Is this possible this way ?

example code to send data :

```
ser = serial.Serial(
    port='/dev/ttyS0',
    baudrate=115200)

def send():
    with open("path_to_my_file_to_send", "rb") as fh:
        while True:
            chunk = fh.read(5120)
            if not chunk: break
            ser.write(chunk)

def reveice():
global receivedData
receivedData = ""
time.sleep(0.001)
while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
    receivedData= ser.read(1)
while True:
    if len(receivedData ) == 1:
        print ("received data")
        break
    else:
        print("no received data")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found something which changes look on this problem. BaudRate only tells me how long single chunk is send. But anyway there was interruption after each chunk but there are caused to big set value for baudrate (values more than 1000000) can provides gaps during transfering files via uart. This gaps if I increase baudrate a little bit was not regular, but if we goes to 4000000 (and we do other operations during transfering file) gaps appear after each chunk.

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is send data from your send then wait for the recieve to send an acknowledgement. This way semd will know its data is successfully recieved and it can send new data then. If not than it can re transmit it or if it recieves the interrupt msg it can stop.
At the send side u can recieve and then send acknowledgement. This acknowledgement could be length of the msgs which can be verified at the send side.

```
ser = serial.Serial(
port='/dev/ttyS0',
baudrate=115200)

def send():
 with open("path_to_my_file_to_send", "rb") as fh:
  while True:
   chunk = fh.read(5120)
    if not chunk: break
    ser.write(chunk)
    #for interupt just send#
    ser.write(b'interupt')

def reveice():
 global receivedData
 receivedData = ""
 time.sleep(0.001)
 while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
  receivedData= ser.read(1)
  if b'interupt' in receivedData:
   #go to recv mode

 while True:
  if len(receivedData) == 1:
   print ("received data")
   break
 else:
  print("no received data")
  break
```

Comment: Main problem is to detect this interruption in while loop :) I add code to received data.

Comment: Re check my ans and see if it helps.

Comment: Problem is that I will get message only sometimes (I will get respond from other side only when It get error with saving chunk or doesn't receive whole part) what provides that I need to have fixed time for it. Still I need to listen for received data after send single chunk but still I don't know how and how long

Comment: so the idea is that whenever your send wants to cause an interrupt u send a specific keyword which means interrupt(here it is the byte form of string interrupt).
To catch this at the ehile loop you can check at each recv call if your specific key word is their meaning if an interupt has occured.
i hope i was able to help